# PostgreSQL How to query String array

Tags: sql, arrays, postgresql

I am trying to write a query to check if an element is within an array of Strings.

Here is my simple select query along with the output

```
select languages from person limit 3;
{CSS,HTML,Java,JavaScript,Python}
{JavaScript,Python,TensorFlow}
{C++,Python}
```

How do I write a query to find all people who have "Java" as a listed language they know? 
I tried following the syntax but it isn't working.

```
select languages from person where languages @> ARRAY['Java']::varchar[];
```

Comment: Getting this error - cannot resolve '`Java`' given input columns:

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You need to use a string constant on the left side, and the ANY operator on the array column:

```
select languages 
from person 
where 'Java' = any(languages);
```

This assumes `languages` is defined as `text[]` or `varchar[]` as your sample output indicates

Answer (score 3):

You can search for more than one pattern replacing '=' operator by the regular expression match operator '~' preceding by a POSIX regular expression, such as:

```
select languages from person where '[Java,Php]' ~ ANY (string_to_array(languages , ','))
```

Answer (score 2):

try this

```
select languages from person where 'Java' = ANY (string_to_array(languages , ','))
```